# Fitting the table on LaTeX beamer slide

Tags: latex, beamer

I am trying to fit a table into a beamer slide. However, I am failing to compress it to fit into a beamer slide. I am using the standard beamer slide template. The last code that is giving me the smallest table:

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{c}}
\hline\hline
                         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
                         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{High blood pressure}\\
\hline
Body mass index (BMI)    &      0.0266\sym{***}\\
                         &     (18.01)         \\
30–39                    &      0.0771\sym{*}  \\
                         &      (2.31)         \\
40–49                    &      0.0994\sym{**} \\
                         &      (2.77)         \\
50–59                    &       0.286\sym{***}\\
                         &      (7.97)         \\
60–69                    &       0.282\sym{***}\\
                         &      (9.65)         \\
70+                      &       0.343\sym{***}\\
                         &      (7.94)         \\
Rural                    &     -0.0150         \\
                         &     (-1.00)         \\
Female                   &      -0.158\sym{***}\\
                         &     (-6.55)         \\
Diabetes status          &      0.0242         \\
                         &      (0.65)         \\
High lead level          &      0.0132         \\
                         &      (0.39)         \\
Black                    &      0.0802\sym{*}  \\
                         &      (2.10)         \\
Female $\times$ Black    &      0.0457         \\
                         &      (0.92)         \\
Female $\times$ 30–39    &   -0.000669         \\
                         &     (-0.02)         \\
Female $\times$ 40–49    &       0.117\sym{*}  \\
                         &      (2.51)         \\
Female $\times$ 50–59    &      0.0381         \\
                         &      (0.81)         \\
Female $\times$ 60–69    &       0.125\sym{***}\\
                         &      (3.34)         \\
Female $\times$ 70+      &       0.152\sym{**} \\
                         &      (2.74)         \\
\hline
Observations             &        4946         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: Please never just post a code fragment. Always make a small, but compilable test file!

Answer (score 0):

Beamer frames are in landscape format. For such a layout, a very tall and slim table is not really well suited. You can adapt your table

- by using three columns instead of two to reduce the height of the table
- use a smaller font size

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\hline\hline
                         &\multicolumn{2}{c}{High blood pressure (1)}\\
\hline
Body mass index (BMI)    &      0.0266\sym{***} &     (18.01)         \\
\hline
Observations             &        4946         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]